# How do you set opacity of an AFrame entity using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, aframe, webvr

I am trying to control the opacity of a text entity on the canvas. So I need to know how to do it using jQuery. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$("#textEntity").attr("material","opacity: 0;");
```

Which is not working. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What text component are you using? If it's bmfont-text, then you need to use its opacity property, not the material's.

Comment: Yes I am using bmfont-text. Opacity property as in <a-entity opacity=0 > ?

Comment: There's an opacity property. https://github.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component#properties

Comment: ya.. Just saw that a while ago..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opacity property of a text entity (bmfont-text) needs to be included in the "bmfont-text" attribute itself. Example :

```
textElem.setAttribute("bmfont-text","text: sampleText; color: #000; opacity: 1.0;");
```